# Primary key for a relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, entity-relationship

I have to relate 2 entities, for a database representing a zoo. 
It is shift patterns for zoo keepers looking after certain enclosures.

We have 
Keeper_Number (FK from "Keeper" table)
Enclosure_Number (FK from "Enclosure" table) 
Shift start
Shift end

Obviously we don't want one person to be able to work in two places at the same time. My question is, am I best making all of these primary keys, so the combination is always unique, or just applying a unique constraint and leaving the table with no foreign key? Apologies for no DDL, my understanding is very limited and I have primarily used the UI of Miscrosoft sequel server express.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the issue is your shift start and end correct? Making those a composite key or adding a constraint would mean they can only be in your shift table once meaning they could only work in one enclosure once, ever, unless you remove the record after the shift ends. So, you need to focus on not having them in two places during the same shift window. instead of applying some constraint, you could just check this on insert and throw an error if they are currently scheduled or working in another enclosure. make sense?

Comment: That does, thank you! My issue is that I have been provided with an ER diagram that explicitly says a start and end datetime are to be in the table. So I am limited to making sure that a keeper can only be in one place at one time, through the data entry

Comment: Ok, that's perfect! I'll show an insert statement for that, pseduocode of course, if you need it

Comment: As it's a complex many to many relationship with 2 foreign keys, I was thinking of using both of those, alongside the start and end date/time info to create a 4 part composite primary key, I just don't know if that is valid..

Comment: It's going to be pretty difficult, to me, to apply a constraint to prevent this. Thus, as it is very common, I'd check if it exists before you insert it to prevent the insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you should probably just check before you insert. There isn't a real good constraint you could apply to prevent duplicate insertion.

```
declare @Keeper_Number int = 5
declare @Enclosure_Number int = 2
declare @startShift datetime = '20181116 08:00:00'
declare @endShift datetime = '20181116 08:00:00'

if exists(select 1 from ShiftTable 
          where Keeper_Number = @Keeper_Number 
          and (     shiftStart between @startShift and @endShift
                or  shiftEnd between @startShift and @endShift)
        )
begin
    raiserror('Employee is already scheduled in another enclousre during this time',16,1)
    return
end
else
begin
    insert into ShiftTable(Keeper_Number, Enclousre_Number, shiftStart, shiftEnd)
    values(@Keeper_Number, @Enclosure_Number, @startShift, @endShift)
end
```